# How to downcast data in a subclass?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm sorry for my question might look very basic or very unnatural.

Assume you have a class A and a subclass A', which has more functions but no more data, and also a class B which has an element of class A. That is, we have something like:

```
class A
{
    ...
};

class A' : public A
{
    (functions only)
};

class B :
{
public:
    something<A> data;
};
```

Is there a way to create a subclass B' of B in a way such that "data" is in fact an element of A' ?
In my situation, B is also a subclass of A but I don't think it's relevant. In fact, an element of A is an hyperface of arbitrary dimension;  B is specifically the dimension 1. "this->data" is the set of hyperfaces that bounds "this", thus it's a set of elements of A. But I know for sure that this is a vertex, which is my class A'.

I would like to avoid downcasting everything and making virtual functions for everything, because I would have to do this for 4 specific dimensions... And also I want to by sure, when an edge is created, that its boundary is composed of vertices.

Comment: The short answer is "no, there isn't". C++ does not work this way. This has all the hallmarks of an XY problem. Rather than asking about how do to what you think is the solution to the real problem, you should explain what the real problem is. The real problem is not how to create your `B` subclass, but whatever the problem is that leads you to believe that you need to create such a subclass. That's what the real question is.

Comment: May be, the _functions only_ shouldn't be methods of `class A'` but free-standing functions. This would eliminate the necessity of adventurous casts. Found this: [Scott Meyers: How Non-Member Functions Improve Encapsulation](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Isn't my second to last paragraph precisely an explanation of what the real problem is? By the way, I am asking not only because I want to solve this precise problem, but because I'm interested in learning something. Don't forget that XY problem is a CS problem, not a sociologic one.

Comment: No, that's not an explanation of what the real problem is. It's the explanation of what you think is the solution to the real problem.